# audio devices not detected, Realtek ALC1220 on fedora

Tags: fedora, audio, realtek

On a newly assembled computer on fedora 38 only "dummy output" appears as sound output's device.

**motherboard** : msi B550 gaming plus
**kernel version** : 6.3.8-200
**linux distro** : fedora 38
**audio chipset** : Realtek ALC1220
**Kernel modules** : snd_hda_intel

`aplay -l` only indicate the nvidia card hdmi output :

```
$ aplay -l
carte 0 : NVidia [HDA NVidia], périphérique 3 : HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sous-périphériques : 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0
carte 0 : NVidia [HDA NVidia], périphérique 7 : HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Sous-périphériques : 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0
carte 0 : NVidia [HDA NVidia], périphérique 8 : HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Sous-périphériques : 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0
carte 0 : NVidia [HDA NVidia], périphérique 9 : HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Sous-périphériques : 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0
```

`lscpi`, for its part, detect the audio card :

```
lspci -knn | grep -i -A4 Audio
2b:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:1aef] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:147d]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
2c:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function [1022:148a]
--
2d:00.4 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller [1022:1487]
    DeviceName: Realtek ALC1220
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:ec56]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

`dmesg | grep snd` returns the following:

```
dmesg | grep snd
[   20.732947] snd_hda_intel 0000:2b:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   20.733008] snd_hda_intel 0000:2b:00.1: Disabling MSI
[   20.733013] snd_hda_intel 0000:2b:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[   20.733070] snd_hda_intel 0000:2d:00.4: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   20.737271] snd_hda_intel 0000:2d:00.4: no codecs found!
[   20.749604] snd_hda_intel 0000:2b:00.1: bound 0000:2b:00.0 (ops nv50_audio_component_bind_ops [nouveau])
```

I tried to change sound related options in the bios without success.
Support for the S1220A chipset was introduced back in the Kernel 4.11 but I am unable to make it work.

Does someone have any clue how I can get sound with this chipset?

Comment: Please report to https://bugzilla.kernel.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Drivers -> Sound (ALSA) and attach `alsa-info.sh`